# Duda iteraciones en listas Python

Tags: python

estuve teniendo algunas problemas para codificar este ejercicio que dejo abajo, Lo que pasa es que cuando el valor esta repetido me devuelve

*El valor no se encuentra repetido y esta en la posicion 0
El valor se encuentra repetido y esta en la posicion 0*

---

```
'''
E9
Escribir una función que reciba una lista y un valor y devuelva la posición en que
encuentra al valor en la lista, si el valor estuviera repetido devolver la primera
aparición, si no estuviera devolver –1.
'''

def iniciar_lista ():
    lista = []
    seguir = True
    while seguir:
        lista.append(int(input("Agregue valores a la lista uno a uno:\n")))
        seguimos = input("Para dejar de agregar valores presione n, sino enter\n")
        if seguimos == 'n':
            seguir = False

    valor = int(input("ingrese el valor que quiere chequear:\n"))
    return lista,valor

def encontrar_valor (valor,lista):
    salida = lista.index(valor)
    contador = 0
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        if lista[i]==valor:
            contador+=1

            if contador>1:
                print("El valor se encuentra repetido y esta en la posicion",salida)

            if contador==1:
                print("El valor no se encuentra repetido y esta en la posicion",salida)

            if contador==0:
                print("-1")

def main():
    lista,valor=iniciar_lista()
    encontrar_valor(valor,lista)

main()
```

Comment: Hmmm, yo separaría la búsqueda de la impresión del resultado. Mientras no lo encuentres, vas a imprimir que no está, luego si lo encuentras imprimes que sí está. Y no hay nada en tu código que interrumpa la ejecución del for, así que siempre vas a recorrer toda la lista diciendo `no, no, no, sí, no, no,...`

Answer (score 1):

Iterar una lista es de los ejercicios que te enseñan a resolver los problemas de manera pythonica, sin embargo hay algunas fallas en la lógica del código que has mostrado.

1. Si el número no está en la lista, debes retornar **-1** pero asumes que ya está al usar `lista.index(valor)`, si no está el devuelve error y no lo controlas.
2. Usas un contador para saber los números repetidos, pero preguntas el valor de `contador` por cada uno de los números de la lista, esto es un error de identación, si sacas estos ifs del bucle, ya funciona resolviendo el ejercicio.

   ```
    def encontrar_valor (valor,lista):
        salida = lista.index(valor)
        contador = 0
        for i in range(len(lista)):
            if lista[i]==valor:
                contador+=1

        if contador>1:
            print("El valor se encuentra repetido y esta en la posicion",salida)

        if contador==1:
            print("El valor no se encuentra repetido y esta en la posicion",salida)

        if contador==0:
            print("-1")
   ```

Ahora esto resuelve *parcialmente* el ejercicio pero se le pueden hacer unos arreglos.

```
import random

# creo una lista aleatoria 
def iniciar_lista(num_valores=10):
    return [random.randint(0,10) for i in range(num_valores)]


def encontrar_valor (valor,lista):
    # preguntamos si el valor está en la lista
    if valor in lista:
        contador = 1
        pos = lista.index(valor)
        # no busques en toda la lista
        # solo busca de esa posición en adelante
        for elemento in lista[pos:]:
            if elemento == valor:
                contador += 1
        
        # puedes concatenar los mensajes
        if contador == 1:
            mensaje = 'El valor no se encuentra repetido '
        else:    
            mensaje = 'El valor se encuentra repetido '
        
        # puedes usar f-strings 
        mensaje += f'y se encuentra en la posición {pos}.'

        return mensaje
    # si no está
    else:
        return -1
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lista = iniciar_lista()
    valor = int(input('Ingrese el valor a buscar.'))
    print(encontrar_valor(valor, lista))
```

Espero te sirva.